# How should I adjust the hidden layers for my Neural Network while working on MNIST's digit recognition set?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I'm just starting to learn about ML and NN. Now, I am working with Jupyter Notebooks and Scikit, and I want to create a Neural Network for hand written digit recogniton.
This is what I have so far in my notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filepath_train = "practice/mnist_train.csv"
filepath_test= "practice/mnist_test.csv"
train_set = pd.read_csv(filepath_train )  #size is 60 000
test_set =  pd.read_csv(filepath_test )   #size is 10 000

x_train = train_set.drop("label", axis=1)
y_train = train_set["label"]

x_test = test_set.drop("label", axis=1)
y_test = test_set["label"]

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(150,100), activation='logistic', alpha=0.1,
                    solver='sgd', tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                    learning_rate_init=.1, verbose=True)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I have to admit, both number of hidden layers/neurons and the activation function I choose randomly, through trial and error. I tried with more, I tried with less, depending on what I see in other notebooks as well.
Either way, whatever I do, the loss value keeps getting stuck around 0.7 - 0.8

[Loss values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k7EH.png)

Answer (score 0):

These layers gave me above 90% accuracy:

```
CNN_model = Sequential()
CNN_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
CNN_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
CNN_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation='relu'))
CNN_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
CNN_model.add(Flatten())
CNN_model.add(Dense(units = 1000, activation='relu'))
CNN_model.add(Dense(units = y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Hmm I don't understand this syntax completely. It seems like a different method than what I am using. What is the number of hidden layers and neurons in your code?